# Turn a regular Windows program into a Windows Service

Tags: windows, windows-services

NetoSoft has a simple [tool](http://emutastic.emulation64.com/netosoft/projects.htm) to create a Windows Service from a regular application. It does work, but obviously is unmaintained now. The tool allows you to register and unregister a service and to start and stop it.

Is there a more up-to-date tool that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a windows service in Visual Studio pretty easily.  Just move the appropriate parts of your code over as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would running it as a user defined service work?

For NT systems you can create a user defined service: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

I suspect there is a slightly different method for Vista/7/2008.